# SQL violation adding foreign key, Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, foreign-keys

I need your help! :(  I'm trying to add foreign key in a existing table with data, but i got a error i think  is because the table has data, I tested all migrations in a new DB and all worked fine, someone know if is possible add the foreign key a table with data??

```
Schema::table('cicles', function(Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('shiftId')->unsigned()->change();
        $table->foreign('shiftId')->references('id')->on('shifts');

    });
```

This when just run the migration to add the foreign key
[image: This when just run the migration to add the foreign key]

This is when run all the migrations

[image]

Comment: Sure, first you have to check that no data violate your foreign key constrain, in case correct data if not possible the constrain is not applicable.

Comment: Oh yes some IDs in 'shifts' were deleted, that is the problem, thank you so much

Comment: set the foreign key to ```nullable``` because you already have data the foreing key will require data. setting the new key  to nullable will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a foreign key constraint if you have existing data which violates the new constraint.  To find the data which violates the constraint, do an outer join.

```
SELECT circles.*
FROM circles
     LEFT OUTER JOIN shifts
       ON circles.shiftId = shifts.id
WHERE shifts.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Oh yes some IDs in 'shifts' were deleted, that is the problem, thank you so much, I didnt know that was a conflict but its logic, again thanks